# android horizontal and vertical recyclerview item decoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I currently have this `Recyclerview` with a solid line ItemDecoration separating the elements.:

[image: current]

but want to have a `RecyclerView` ItemDecoration with a style like this one:

[image: want]

This is my decoration with just solid vertical and horizontal lines without line spaces like my example :

```
public class GridDividerDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private static final int[] ATTRS = {android.R.attr.listDivider};

    private Drawable mDivider;
    private int mInsets;

    public GridDividerDecoration(Context context) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();

        mInsets = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_insets);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }

    public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        if (parent.getChildCount() == 0) return;

        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params =
                    (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            final int left = child.getLeft() - params.leftMargin - mInsets;
            final int right = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin + mInsets;
            final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin + mInsets;
            final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

    public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params =
                    (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin + mInsets;
            final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final int top = child.getTop() - params.topMargin - mInsets;
            final int bottom = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin + mInsets;
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.set(mInsets, mInsets, mInsets, mInsets);
    }
}
```

anyone can help how to set some spaces between lines ?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted images of what your code does now and what you are trying to achieve. "Set spaces between lines" is rather open to interpretation.

Comment: @Kuffs 
my code show it :
http://uupload.ir/files/c10s_untitled.png
i want to set spaces between the lines

Comment: is it required to have it as a item decoration, it can be simply a part of item view?

Comment: @Arpit i don't know. i have to do it. i thinke it is a shape in the decoration design. please help me if you can !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to have slightly shorter lines so just amend your bounds.

e.g:

For the vertical line, you have:

```
mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

so just change the top and bottom offsets like this:

```
mDivider.setBounds(left, top + 10, right, bottom - 10);
```

Do a similar thing for the horizontal lines but change the left and right offsets.

You can experiment with the actual values until you get the effect you want.